# Best way to search for specific attribute of Object

Tags: java, list, search

I have a List of Objects, e.g.

```
public class Foo {
   private String str;
   private Integer i;
   // Getter
}

//

List<Foo> list;
```

Now I want to search for e.g. all Object where String str is equal to `someString` What would be the best way to archieve that? Of course I could iterate over the whole List und compare every Object with my search-String (or search-Integer, or whatever I am lookin for), but I am wondering if there is a ready solution for this (in my opinion where basic task) e.g. in the Collection-Framework or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `guava` you could do something like this:

```
Foo result = Iterables.find(list, new Predicate<Foo>() {
    public boolean apply(Foo foo) { return foo.getInteger() == 3; }
});
```

---

Or in the upcoming `java8` you can use lambda expressions:

```
list.stream()
    .filter( f -> f.getInteger() == 3)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And you won't need a 3rd party library for that :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at google's Guava and filters api:

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained